# SharePoint 2013: Start a workflow when a value in specific column is changed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I would like that  my workflow will run only if a value on a specific colunm will **change**.
Is there a way to do it without using a third colunm ?

Comment: Are you using designer workflows or visual studio workflows??

Comment: Hi, designer workflows .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following link :

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/watch-this-run-a-workflow-when-a-specific-field-changes-HA010256419.aspx

I think you might need some other hidden column to achieve this in sharepoint designer workflow,.

Otherwise, you may create an itemupdating/fieldUpdated event handler and start the workflow programatically.

Comment: The links is dead, I think this links gives the same information: http://officepowerups.com/2013/07/09/send-email-when-specific-field-changes-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow which will start on "Item Create" and you can place the below action,

**Wait for Field Change in Current Item** - Used to wait for a field to be changed in the current item.

**`The Wait for Field Change in Current Item`** action contains two editable regions, as shown in the figure.

[image]

The editable regions are:

•Field:   The field in the item that should be monitored for change.

•Value:   The value that the field should equal in order for the workflow to proceed.

Once a field has changed the workflow continues.